# what is the real advanteges of RMI call back?

Tags: java, rmi

I have read a lot about RMI call back but I need to know the advantages of using that and is there any special code for making RMI callback?

Answer (score 1):

A callback is a pattern whereby the guy you have called can in turn call a method on *you*. It means that you don't have to ship him all the data he needs in one go: he can ask *you,* and he can do that when he needs it, which might be a long time after you call him.

Having said that, RMI callbacks aren't much use in practice except within LANs, as callbacks in general are a *prima facie* security breach and generally disallowed by firewall administrators. So don't get too keen on them.